# Validation, exception handling, security etc. when using Spring Reactive WebFlux

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-validator, spring-webflux

I was evaluating *Spring Reactive WebFlux* for a new project, and it looks quite interesting. But I'm unsure on how best to handle validation, security etc. For example, I'm used to having `@Valid` annotation in controllers for validating parameters, like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users")
public User signup(@RequestBody @Valid UserCommand user) {
    ...
}
```

But now, when I now use a `Mono<UserCommand>` as the parameter, `@Valid` no more seems to work. Similarly, I guess other annotations like `@JsonView`, service method validation using `@Validated`, Spring Security annotations that refer to parameters (like `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'edit')")`) may not work with `Mono<T>` either. Do they?

Secondly, what about the `@ControllerAdvice`s for catching exceptions? Would they work? What would be the best way to handle errors if they won't?

Comment: Should not it be `public Mono<User> signup(@RequestBody @Valid UserCommand user)` ?

Comment: I've mentioned the old signature. The new signature could be public `Mono<User> signup(@RequestBody @Valid Mono<UserCommand> user) `. My question is how to validate the `Mono<UserCommand>` parameter, etc.

Comment: http://www.sparkbit.pl/spring-web-reactive-rest-controllers/

Comment: Yeah, I had gone through that, which tells that the things I've raised were not addressed when the post was written. Any progress, or we go handling things manually for now?

Comment: There are too many questions here, please try reducing the scope of this question and opening separate ones.